# Redux app: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have error in my reducer:
[image]

props `actual`- this is the time the airplane departure or arrival, this property is located in my API
API has this structure:

```
{"body":{
"departure":[{actual: value},{term: value}],
"arrival":[{....},{......}]}
}
```

code:

airplanes.js(reducer)

```
import { searchFilter } from "../components/app";

export function reducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_SHIFT":
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        shift: action.shift
      });
    case "SET_SEARCH":
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        search: action.search.toLowerCase()
      });
    case "RUN_FILTER":
      var newData = state.data[action.shift].filter(x => {
        return (
          x.actual &&
          x.actual.includes(
            state.day
              .split("-")
              .reverse()
              .join("-")
          )
        );
      });
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        shift: action.shift || state.shift,
        search: action.search || state.search,
        filteredData: searchFilter(state.search, newData)
      });
    case "LOAD_DATA_START":
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        day: action.day
      });
    case "LOAD_DATA_END":
      var newData = action.payload.data[state.shift].filter(x => {
        return (
          x.actual &&
          x.actual.includes(
            action.payload.day
              .split("-")
              .reverse()
              .join("-")
          )
        );
      });
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        data: action.payload.data,
        shift: Object.keys(action.payload.data)[0],
        filteredData: searchFilter(state.search, newData)
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

app.js(main component)

```
import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchData } from "../actions";
import TableData from "./TableData";
import TableSearch from "./TableSearch";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import "./app.css";

export function searchFilter(search, data) {
  return data.filter(n => n.term.toLowerCase().includes(search));
}

const days = ["23-08-2019", "24-08-2019", "25-08-2019"];

class Root extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onFetchData(days[this.props.propReducer.day]);
  }

  render() {
    const { onFilter, onSetSearch, onFetchData } = this.props;

    const { search, shift, data, filteredData } = this.props.propReducer;

    console.log(filteredData);

    return (
      <div>
        <Header/>
        <h1>SEARCH FLIGHT</h1>
        <TableSearch
          value={search}
          onChange={e => onSetSearch(e.target.value)}
          onSearch={() => onFilter()}
        />

        {days &&
          days.map((day, i) => (
            <button
              key={day}
              onClick={() => onFetchData(day)}
              className={i === day ? "active" : ""}
            >
              {day}
            </button>
          ))}
        <br />
            <div className="buttonShift">
        {data &&
          Object.keys(data).map(n => (

            <button 
              data-shift={n}
              onClick={e => onFilter({ shift: e.target.dataset.shift })}
              className={n === shift ? "active" : "noActive"}
            >
              {n} 
            </button>
          ))}
          </div>
        {data && <TableData data={filteredData} />}
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export const ConnectedRoot = connect(
  state => state,
  dispatch => ({
    onFilter: args => dispatch({ type: "RUN_FILTER", ...args }),
    onSetSearch: search => dispatch({ type: "SET_SEARCH", search }),
    onFetchData: day => dispatch(fetchData(day))
  })
)(Root);
```

by the way the function `searchFilter` is written property `term` and not property `actual`. Maybe the problem is partly due to this, but not only this, because I tried to replace the `term` with `actual`, but the error remained.

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `onFilter` action creator in `app.js`:

```
onFilter: args => dispatch({ type: "RUN_FILTER", ...args })
```

When called without the first argument:

```
<TableSearch ... onSearch={() => onFilter()} />
```

Then in `airplanes.js` reducer, `action.shift` is undefined, so `state.data[action.shift]` is undefined too and `state.data[action.shift].filter` is a TypeError.

**To fix, you can use a default value**:

```
state.data[action.shift || state.shift].filter
```

---

However, there is an additional problem, inside `TableSearch.js` you call:

```
<button ... onClick={() => onSearch(value)}>
```

So you shouldn't ignore the value in `app.js`:

```
<TableSearch ... onSearch={(value) => onFilter({search: value})} />
```

...and use `action.search || state.search` inside your `.filter(...)` depending on the business logic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Could you help me correct the sandbox errors? I'm just a beginner in react and redux and didn't understand everything what you wrote and where to fix it.I understood something, but not everything.I just think it will be faster than I will ask you, where and what line to replace in the code. My sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-1yuhe

Comment: please ask what EXACTLY was not clear, a better explanation might help future users too.

Comment: ok:1) In aiplanes.js I changed: ```state.data[action.shift || state.shift].filter```
but also below I have this line:
```case "LOAD_DATA_END":
      var newData = action.payload.data[state.shift].filter(x => {```
does it also need to be modified somehow?
2)  ```TableSearch ... onSearch={(value) => onFilter({search: value})} />```
should i write in app.js that?
3) and use ```action.search || state.search``` inside your ```.filter(...)``` .In what file and in which lines should I change it?

Comment: 1) it depends whether you dispatch the `LOAD_DATA_END` action with `shift` payload - probably not. 
2) yes, everywhere where `<TableSearch>` is used. 
3) no idea what is the desired behaviour, how the search should work. but somewhere inside `case "RUN_FILTER":`

Comment: can i write to you an email that writes in your github? it will be more convenient to write than in the comments?

Comment: everything is working, i just wanted to ask something else at the expense of my application

Comment: I do have a day job and personal life, helping here on stackoverflow just a few hours per week. you can try to write me about an interesting open source project that only needs a little more help, but no promises I will put it on top of my list any time soon.

Comment: I understood, can you see my new question related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58789147/where-did-i-make-the-mistake-of-changing-my-search-filter-and-how-to-fix-it