# Where did I make the mistake of changing my search filter? And how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a list of airplanes departing or arriving at the airport and i also had a search filter where i enter the time of arrival or departure and filtering of the airplanes. I do this using the `actual` property of my API. But I needed to change my search. Now I need to search by flight number - the `planeTypeID.code` property of my API. But when I changed it, stopped showing a list of airplanes. What is my mistake and how to fix it?

I just instead `actual` everywhere wrote `["planeTypeID.code"]` and delete method:
`.split("-").reverse().join("-")`

OLD version:
small part airplane.js(reducer)

```
case "RUN_FILTER":
      var newData = state.data[action.shift || state.shift].filter(x => {
        return (
          x.actual &&               
          x.actual.includes(         
            state.day
              .split("-")           
              .reverse()             
              .join("-")               
          )
        );
      });

    case "LOAD_DATA_END":
      var newData = action.payload.data[state.shift].filter(x => {
        return (
          x.actual &&                      
          x.actual.includes(                   
            action.payload.day
              .split("-")                             
              .reverse()                
              .join("-")                 
          )
        );
      });
```

small part app.js(main component)

```
export function searchFilter(search, data) {
  return data.filter(n => n.actual.toLowerCase().includes(search)); 
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

NEW version:

small part airplane.js(reducer)

```
    case "RUN_FILTER":

      var newData = state.data[action.shift || state.shift].filter(x => {
        return (
          x["planeTypeID.code"] &&                   // Сhange 
          x["planeTypeID.code"].includes(            // Сhange 
            state.day
                                                      // delete                                
          )
        );
      });
      return Object.assign({}, state, {

    case "LOAD_DATA_END":
      var newData = action.payload.data[state.shift].filter(x => {
        return (
          x["planeTypeID.code"] &&                   // Сhange        
          x["planeTypeID.code"].includes(            // Сhange   
            action.payload.day
                                                     // delete                                    
          )
        );
      });
```

small part app.js(main component)

```
export function searchFilter(search, data) {
  return data.filter(n => n["planeTypeID.code"].toLowerCase().includes(search)); // Сhange   
}
```

All project code in sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-jj6mu

Comment: please modify your code and only leave the part which is important

Comment: @iLiA done. Сan you help me?

Comment: your code does not seems rigth. first thing that i got in my eye was that you were returning data in reducer with parenthesees. with return you are returning object (new state) so you should use `{ }` instead. also, you are splitting `state.day` so you are mutating state and that's not good practice, hence it will not re-render component, mapping `day` as its prop. my advice would be to read redux's docs carefully and implement it after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example value of `x["planeTypeID.code"]` is "B734", of `state.day` "23-08-2019" => those are 2 different fields => you will get an empty array when you filter by `x["planeTypeID.code"].includes(state.day)` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

After debugging via comments, the most likely solution is:

```
x["planeTypeID.code"].toLowerCase().includes(action.search || state.search)
```

---

I recommend to [Get Started with Debugging JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript) as a generic first step to questions that start with:

> Where did I make the mistake...

...before posting to Stack Overflow.

Comment: maybe even [Tania's Top Ten Tutorials](https://taniarascia.substack.com/p/tanias-top-ten-tutorials)

Comment: how to fix this? I need to filter by ```planeTypeID.code```

Comment: Fixing the problem requires understanding of the expected behaviour. I do not understand what is expected, so I am unable to fix this particular problem for you. StackOverflow is here to match people who have a technical question with volunteers who might know the answer; but you could benefit more from guidance from a more senior team member at your workplace.

Comment: Assuming the `planeTypeID.code` part is correct, then the `state.day` is incorrect and you have to replace it with something related to the flight number from state, e.g. `action.flightNumber || state.flightNumber` but I don't see anything like that in your state. Where you store the flight number information provided by the user?

Comment: my Api have structure:
```{"body": 
"deparute": [{"actual":value,   "planeTypeID.code": value }, {....}],
"arrival":[{"actual:value",   "planeTypeID.code: value" }, {...}]
}
```
this my API: https://api.iev.aero/api/flights/24-08-2019
And in file index.js I have this code:

```const store = createStore(
  reducer, 
  {
    propReducer: {
      day: 1,
      data: [],
      filteredData: [],
      search: "",
      shift: "departure"
    }
  }
 ,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);```

hat is,my data is stored in data and filtered data is stored in filteredData
```

Comment: also you can to see sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-olbgn  (who is not yet working) I think it will be clearer that I need it

Comment: Out of the keys `day`, `data`, `filteredData`, `search` or `shift`, the most likely seems to be `search` => you can try to use `x["planeTypeID.code"].toLowerCase().includes(action.search || state.search)` on lines 16 and 32 of `airplanes.js`... is that what you need?

Comment: Hurray! everything works as it should! thank you very much! can i ask you the last question? Now the aiplane's arrival and departure time is displayed like this: ```2019-08-24T12:12:59Z``` but I need it to be ```12:12``` (only hours and minutes for all airplanes)how can this be implemented?

Comment: Thank you again! I will try